# Do you need an access token to post on app user's wall as themself?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to post on app user's wall from my application as themself. I'm using the PHP SDK 3.2.2. Here's my codes so far.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(
    array(
        'appId' => 1234567890abcdefg,
        'secret' => 1234567890abcdefg,
        'cookie' => true,
    )
);
$facebookId = '1234567890';
$status = array(
    'message' => 'Message',
    'name' => 'Name',
    'description' => 'Description',
    'link' => 'http://www.google.com',
    'picture' => 'http://www.something.com/placehold.gif',
);
$facebook->api('/'.$facebookId.'/feed/', 'post', $status);
```

This will work fine and it will post a status update on the user's wall (e.g. App User shared a link via app-dev.) without having me to specify the access token.

I'm reading the How-To from Facebook and it says that

> If your app publishes on behalf of its users and requires an access
>   token with no expiration time for the purpose of publishing, you
>   should use an App Access Token.

So is it required for me to specify an access token? If yes, where to I specify them? Thanks.

Comment: Permission is definitively required for this – so just have implemented some kind of login before I guess?

Comment: Yes, user has granted permission when user authorizes app during login. But I'm still able to post as the user without the access token.

Comment: Once you have granted an app publish permission, that app is also able to post to your wall on your behalf using its _app_ access token, and this is what the SDK sets automatically if it can not find another token.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP SDK has a [`setAccessToken()` function](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-setAccessToken/). You can use that to set the token to your application access token.

You can easily get your app token by combining your application id and secret separated by a pipe (`|`) character, like this:

```
$fbConfig = array(
  'appId' => 1234567890abcdefg,
  'secret' => 1234567890abcdefg,
  'cookie' => true,
)
$facebook = new Facebook($fbConfig);
$facebook->setAccessToken($fbConfig['appId'] .'|'. $fbConfig['secret']);
```

You'll now be able to perform actions on behalf of your application.

Comment: Hi Lix, I am able to post on the wall. However I'm just curious how I could do it without an access token. Thanks for the answer. :)